# Monodevelop on Ubuntu 8.10

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, mono-framework

How do I install Monodevelope on Ubuntu 8.10??
I'm running it on VirtualBox on Vista

Comment: I dont have access to superuser

Comment: Password is on blog.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/4503/howto-install-recent-mono-on-a-linux-distro-other-than-suse-e-g-debian-ubuntu) similar question on serverfault.

**summary / hints**:

- ubuntu is based on debian
- look into synaptec package manager
- find and add a repository that published the mono-dev package.